# Interface instance

Tags: c#, .net, instance-variables

My Question is If IEnumberable is interface then Why .Net allow to instantiate IEnumerable instance ?

```
IEnumerable <string> Errors= new IEnumerable<string>()
```

Why We not instantiate our own Interface just like they do?

Comment: Where does .net instantiate an interface? Are you sure it's not just exposing an object that implements an interface as that interface?

Comment: `Error: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'` Can you give us an example of some code that actually compiles?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create instance of Interface your given code will throw you error.

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Yes you can initialize interface variable with class which is implementing it:

```
IEnumerable <string> Errors = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why .Net allow to instantiate IEnumerable instance

Well can you do this?

```
IEnumerable <string> Errors= new IEnumerable<string>()
```

you should get this error when you try to do it

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'